# Django Formset Iteration go wrong

Tags: django, forms, formset

I am trying to get the cleaned_data for each form in a formset, using a normal iteration (just like what shown in Django documentation):

```
MyFormSet = formset_factory(form=MyForm, formset=MyBaseFormSet)
my_form_set = MyFormSet(request.POST or None, initial = my_data, prefix = 'myform')
```

After that I'm validating and trying to iterate through each form and print it values like this:

```
for f in my_form_set.forms:
    print(f.cleaned_data)
```

But the result that I get is somekind like this:

```
<QueryDict: {"myform-0-field_a" : "this is a", "myform-1-field_a" : "this is second a"}>
<QueryDict: {"myform-0-field_a" : "this is a", "myform-1-field_a" : "this is second a"}>
```

I was expecting to get individual pair of key and values, but instead, for each iteration, I get the whole thing of POST data.

I was expecting something like this:

Iteration 0:

```
"field_a" : "this is a"
```

Iteration 1:

```
"field_a" : "this is second a"
```

Where do I miss?

Thanks

Comment: That is indeed what you should get. I think you need to post the form and formset classes, and the full view.

Answer (score 2):

The labels each form field have needs to be unique, otherwise there is no way telling
from which form what data came. "myform-0-field_a" , "myform-1-field_a" are the keys/labels
The browser send you all fields in one post.

since f.cleaned data seams to be a subclassed dict this will probably work

```
    for k, v in f.cleaned_data.items():
        print k.split('-')[-1], v
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

Comment: Thanks. but it seems like the same. Each iteration it display the whole thing (form 1 data and form 2 data) :(.